# Need to get date of last Thursday of a given month in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Need to determine any given month's last Thursday. If given month is current month, and the last Thursday has passed, need to raise an exception. I am trying to use `datetime` module, but can't find a straightforward way of doing this.

Edit: seems like my question was not clear enough. The function I am looking for will return the date of the final Thursday of a given month, such that no date following the returned date in the month shall be a Thursday. The problem seems to have been effectively solved by CrackaJackDev and af3ld. Thank you for that. Also a big thanks to Bahrom for crucial edits and correction. I am new to this community, so sorry if my question was not well organized. I shall try harder next time.

Comment: I have no clue what you're saying. Could you elaborate on your question a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't depend on any external packages:

```
import datetime, calendar

def LastThInMonth(year, month):
    # Create a datetime.date for the last day of the given month
    daysInMonth = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]   # Returns (month, numberOfDaysInMonth)
    dt = datetime.date(year, month, daysInMonth)

    # Back up to the most recent Thursday
    offset = 4 - dt.isoweekday()
    if offset > 0: offset -= 7                          # Back up one week if necessary
    dt += datetime.timedelta(offset)                    # dt is now date of last Th in month

    # Throw an exception if dt is in the current month and occurred before today
    now = datetime.date.today()                         # Get current date (local time, not utc)
    if dt.year == now.year and dt.month == now.month and dt < now:
        raise Exception('Oops - missed the last Thursday of this month')

    return dt

for month in range(1, 13): print(LastThInMonth(2016, month))

2016-01-28
2016-02-25
2016-03-31
2016-04-28
2016-05-26
2016-06-30
2016-07-28
2016-08-25
2016-09-29
2016-10-27
2016-11-24
2016-12-29
```

Answer (score 6):

For the first part of your question, I like [relativedelta](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) from the date.utils library.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, TH

def get_thurs(dt):
    print (dt + relativedelta(day=31, weekday=TH(-1)))

get_thurs(date(2016, 7, 7))
get_thurs(date(2019, 6, 4))


2016-07-28
2019-06-27
```

For the second part, I think you want something kind of like this:

```
def get_thurs(dt):
    return (dt + relativedelta(day=31, weekday=TH(-1)))


def later_date(dt):
    if dt.month == date.today().month:  # checks if in current month
        if get_thurs(dt).day > dt.day:  # checks if last Thurs has passed
            raise Exception
        else:
            print "It is before that Thursday"


later_date(date(2016, 7, 23))
later_date(date(2016, 7, 29))


It is before that Thursday
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculator/bw_events_cookies/tests/ideas.py", line 31, in <module>
    later_date(date(2016, 7, 23))
  File "calculator/bw_events_cookies/tests/ideas.py", line 26, in later_date
    raise Exception
Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different aprroach:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def GetLastWeekdayOfMonth(year,month,weekday):
        lastDayOfMonth = datetime.datetime(year,month,calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1]) 
        
while lastDayOfMonth.weekday() != weekday:
            lastDayOfMonth-=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return lastDayOfMonth
```

Worked very well for me!

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it without installing outside package:

```
import datetime as dt
import calendar  
td = dt.date(2021,8,5)
monthlength = calendar.monthrange(td.year, td.month)[1]
expdate = dt.date(td.year, td.month, monthlength)
while True:
    expdate = expdate - dt.timedelta(1)
    if expdate.weekday() == 3:          # 3 is thursday
        break
print(expdate)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct however little tweak to make it perfect.
Add below lines just after while 
`code`     
 if expdate.weekday() == 3:          # 3 is thursday
          break 
`code`

Answer (score 0):

This function will return 'YYYY-mm-dd' string of the date of last Thursday of the given month, to raise an exception, you can parse date and compare with current date.

```
import calendar 

def last_thursday_date(year, month):
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month)
    last_thurs_date = cal[4][3]
    if month < 10:
        thurday_date = str(year)+'-0'+ str(month)+'-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    else:
        thurday_date = str(year) + '-' + str(month) + '-' + str(last_thurs_date)
    return thurday_date
```